# How to trigger a code segment when a certain function is called for testing in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

My system has a long and complicated flow to it. For simplicity's sake, lets say it looks like this:

```
def main():
 function_1()
 function_2()
 .
 .
 function_n()
```

I want to create a unit test that will trigger on a certain function, e.g:

```
def test():
  main()
  function_3.called():  # need help with this line
    some_code()
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using Pytest?

Comment: What do you mean trigger? People usually have tests separated from the code that's being tested. You could add assertions to the code? Idk if this helps, but Python decorators are a common way to do something "every time this function is called".

Comment: @Dennis  The code is separate from the test.
In the test, I call the main() function.  but unlike a regular run, I'd like to add some specific behaviour when function_3 is called.

I'm asking if there's a way to know when function_3 was called, and perhaps add a callback or something similar that would run during the test

Comment: I think the keyword you're looking for is "mocking".

Comment: @Dennis  I know I can mock the function, but I don't see how that will help me trigger some code after its called

Comment: Maybe you can explain what you actually want to do. What is the inserted code? Why can't you insert it by mocking `function_3` with a function that calls the original code?